# How to get a text / return(JSON ) in my API code with Watson?

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

In my example,
If the user clicks the button "Yes" Will return a conversation text. But I'd like it to return a value from my output, the return from my `AJAX` `Post` example, which is currently only coming from the "`alert (output.request.number)`". 
How to make? Follow the codes:

In the conversation Intents: `#goodbye` and two entities: `@goodbye:yes` and `@goodbye:no`. If my client-side recognize the intent and user clicks the button "yes", will **return something**.

My JSON Advanced (Conversation Service)

```
    {
      "output": {
        "text": "You can finish the conversation? \n \n 
<button id=\"button-yes\" onclick=\"OneFunction();\">Yes</button> 
<button id=\"button-no\" onclick=\"OtherFunction();\">No</button>"
      }
    }
```

I need the return of `alert(output.request.number)` to come in Watson's conversation flows if the user clicks on the button.

The **JS** code:

```
function OneFunction(firstParameter, secondParameter){
 console.log(firstParameter);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/request/create',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "dataOne":firstParameter,
            "synchronize":false,              
            }
        }), 
    success:function(output, input, response) {
      console.log(output);
     // alert(output.request.number);
      var responseText = null;
      var outputTest = {};
      outputTest = output.request.number;
      var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
      // console.log(latestResponse);
      var context = latestResponse.context;
      Api.sendRequest = ("Yes", + outputTest);  // THIS RETURN one number of request
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I got it completely, but if you want the Watson return a script or a method call in it's textual response then that is not a good use case for this. A better approach is to return this kind of information on `context` or `output` field. Working with JSON in JS should be straightforward, so to access output field you should be ok to write  `var outputField = latestResponse.output;` . You'll then check if there is e.g. attribute `alert` with some text in the `output` field and if yes you display the alert to the user in JS.

Comment: I want to return in the same conversation, not in "alert". After the user clicks yes, it will execute this action and return a value that I received in response within the conversation.

Comment: So you want to propagate the clicking on yes to the Watson Conversation. You could do it by simply sending "yes" textual input to the conversation and in the conversation you would have "yes" handled in the dialog nodes. Now you could also process this special kind of input by setting special variables on the `input` part of the JSON request and you could check this in the dialog nodes, but for this particular use case I would simply send the "click" as a "yes" textual input to the service...

Comment: Can you show an example, please?

Comment: Because in addition to want to return a "yes" in the conversation, I want to return a value that together, which in this case would be (output.request.number), in alert the value appears normally, but when I put in variable, it does not appear and error: Context must be of type \"object\"

Comment: To get a complete picture, we may need to see the code where you call the WCS api. But one idea could be that you have a mixed object being sent. Part of your API.sendRequest is Text, the other part is a number. You could try making both parts into one string. 
Try API.sendRequest("Yes"+ output.request.number.toString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try it and work, the error is just a `,` between `("Yes" + outputTest);` 
But yours information was **essential** to this, thanks, @Michal Bida and @timd. :

```
success:function(output, input, response) {
      console.log(output);
     // alert(output.request.number);
      var responseText = null;
      var outputTest = {};
      outputTest = output.request.number;
      var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
      // console.log(latestResponse);
      var context = latestResponse.context;
      Api.sendRequest = ("Yes" + outputTest);  // THIS RETURN one number of request
```